# Semantic markup for self-reference?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

We include a reference text for our content which is included at the top of pages when users print out the content.

In HTML4 and XHTML1.1, this was marked up as:

```
<div id="reference">
  Our product name. Our organisation; 2013 June. Available from: https://oursite.com
</div>
```

We are rewriting our templates as HTML5, and I was wondering if I should be using `<cite>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cite` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) is not appropriate here. You may only use it for "the title of a work" that is "being quoted", "referenced in detail" or "mentioned in passing". But you are giving information about the very same page, not some other work.

I think you may use the [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element):

> A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like.

But instead of `footer`, the [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) may also be appropriate here:

> A `header` typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids.

It might help to see the whole page structure, but taking your specific example into account, I’d probably go with `header`.

If the information only applies to the main content (and not the whole page content), make sure to include the `footer`/`header` in the sectioning element (`article`/`section`) for the main content. If the information is about the whole page, include the `footer`/`header` as child of `body` (with no other sectioning element as parent).

Comment: Thanks - I was getting a bit stuck parsing the spec, but you've explained things pretty well.